# What does this popup mean in Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

What does it mean if a pop up says

> The bean has appeared in the basement.

I haven't tried anything cause I do not know what it is.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you unlock a new item, you'll get a notification that says "[Item] has appeared in the basement!", where [Item] is the  item that was unlocked. This means that the specified item now has a chance of appearing during any future runs.

In this case, you unlocked [The Bean](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bean), which is an active item that releases a cloud of poison gas that damages nearby enemies.